# phpMailer script for a contact form

Tags: php, form, email

I've just downloaded a script and would like to use it as a contact form on my site. The problem is I'm a front-end dev with little knowledge of securing PHP code. So, could you please have a look and let me know if there are any glaring problems with security with this script that uses phpMailer to send?

As you can see, I haven't done much with the SMTP setting at the bottom, but it still seems to work ok on my server.

```
<?php

$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$site_owners_email = 'email@someemail.com'; // Replace this with your own email address
$site_owners_name = 'Name'; // replace with your name

if (strlen($name) < 2) {
    $error['name'] = "Please enter your name";    
}

if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address";    
}

if (strlen($comments) < 1) {
    $error['comments'] = "Please leave a comment.";
}

if (!$error) {

    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->Subject = "Website Contact Form";
    $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
    $mail->AddAddress('email@someemail.com', 'Name');
    $mail->Body="
    Name: $name
    Email: $email
    Comments: $comments";


    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "email@someemail.com"; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = ""; // SMTP password    

    $mail->Send();

    echo "<li class='success' id='successMessage' > Congratulations, " . $name . " We've received your email. We'll be in touch as soon as we possibly can!</li><li id='closeBtn'><a href='#'>close</a></li><li id='homeLink'><a href='http://mosaicwebstudio.com/sandbox/forms/mod-ajax2' >return to home page</a></li>";

} # end if no error
else {

    $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? "<li>" . $error['name'] . "</li> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? "<li>" . $error['email'] . "</li> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['comments'])) ? "<li>" . $error['comments'] . "</li>" : null;

    echo $response;
} # end if there was an error sending

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

As [@e-sushi remarked in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/28424/27237): you're still vulnerable to header injections. Though his approach is rather complex, and (when applied to `$email`, not required if you validate the email address the way I do (explained further down), but for the subject, and message body, you could use these simpler, and (IMO, therefore) better ways to tackle the header-injection issue:

```
$mail->Body = str_ireplace(
    array("%0a", "%0d", '0x0A'), '',//PHPMailer replaces \r\n already for you
   'your string here...'
); 
//a Core-function alternative:
$body = 'your string here';
filter_var($body, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);//will alter $body
$mail->Body = $body;
```

More details on the caveats/benefits of each approach [can be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428076/PHP-Mail-Injection-Protection-and-E-Mail-Validatio). Because you're setting the `$name` along side the email address, too as the *from* of the email, you *should* pass the `$name` value to either one of these filters, too.

Your code is attempting to validate an email address using a regular expression that is, at best, slightly off. There is a built-in function that can validate email addresses, without an inaccurate, too restrictive and slow regular expression, called [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/filter_var).

```
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    exit('Invalid email');
}
```

The result is that, while your regex doesn't allow for: `some.name@site.info` to be used as an email address (even though it's valid), `filter_Var` *will* accept it.
Unlike your regex, which, because it uses the `s` modifier allows for line-breaks in your email (for some reason), this won't... not blindly.
If, however, you wish to keep on using a regular expression, here's a PCRE expression that is (almost) fully RFC822 compliant:

```
/(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ 
\t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\0
31]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\
](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+
(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:
(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\
r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)
*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+
|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r
\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031
]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?
:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?
:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?
:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?
[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|
\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>
@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"
(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?
:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[
\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-
\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;
:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([
^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"
.\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\
]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\
[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\
r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]
|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \0
00-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\
.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,
;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?
:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[
^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]
]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:,\s*(
?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[
\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?
:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|
\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:
[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\
]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["
()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>
@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,
;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[
"()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\
.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)?;\s*)/
```

Source: [ex-parrot](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

I think it's clear which one of the validations is the more elegant one...

The name (`$name`) is a trimmed version of the POST var. That's good, because you *know* that, if the `strlen($name) > 2`, you're not just counting whitespace. However, you still *are* counting possible whitespace-only input when validating the `$comment` variable.

I'd suggest additional processing on both of these values:

```
$name = trim(html_entity_decode($_POST['name']));
if (strlen($name) < 2 || !preg_match('/^[^\d]+\s*[^\d]*/',$name))
{//nobody is called R2D2 in real-life!
    exit('name is too short ( < 2 chars) or contains numeric chars');
}
$comment = trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($_POST['comment'])));
if (!strlen($comment))
{//empty comment
   exit('No comment supplied');
}
```

As you can see, I've also used `html_entity_decode` and, for the comments at least `strip_tags` to remove any markup that might have been passed. This is often overlooked, so if I were to post a comment saying:

```
&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;
```

Even `trim` would see this as a valid comment, whereas it actually is little more than whitespace

Comment: `//nobody is called R2D2 in real-life!` – Well, let’s just hope **[Kenny Baker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenny_Baker_%28English_actor%29)** never tries to contact him using that contact form. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing whatever users enter in the comment form via email **unfiltered**.

In simpler words: you will need to filter all data the user enters, to make sure you are safe from the usual mail injects.

Example:

```
function my_filter($data)
{
    $data = preg_replace('=((<CR>|<LF>|0x0A/%0A|0x0D/%0D|\\n|\\r)\S).*=i', '', $data);
    $data= trim(preg_replace('=[\r\n]+=', '', $data)); 
    return $data;
}
```

At least run the user-defined data trough the filter to be safe from email header injects etc. just in case the *PHP mailing class* you are using doesn't do that for you.

```
$name = my_filter($_POST['name']);
$email = my_filter($_POST['email']);
$comments = my_filter($_POST['comments']);
```

Then, it should be somewhat safe.

Another thing you might considder adding is some kind of captcha to your mailing/comment form to prevent bots to auto-post thousands of messages without anyone stopping them.

Comment: `filter_var` to validate the email is all you need. `PHPMailer` does sanitize (not enough, though) the input, but your approach is, IMO, a tad over the top...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Note that **OP did not specify which version of PHP is used**. `filter_var` is only available in PHP 5.2.0 and later versions. **Also**, `filter_var` has a lot of problems! Eg: [will not validate valid domain names with foreign characters](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#111828), [there are email addresses FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL rejects but RFC5321 specifically permits](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#112492), [it will not protect you from injection-attacks](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#108769), and much more…

Comment: Come on, 5.2 was released about 8 years ago, is no longer actively maintained either. The common and safe assumption to make is people are working with PHP 5.3 and up (oh, and `filter_var` has its problems, true enough, but since its release, there have been a lot of changes and tweaks to the email filter)

Comment: Your *“common and safe assumption”* breaks as soon as you hit Murphy's law in relation to production servers. Actually, you´re saying it yourself: *“since its release, there have been a lot of changes and tweaks to the email filter”*, which already hints at the differences and issues of different PHP versions. Practically, the “changes and tweaks” contradict your *”safe assumption”*. Anyway – since OP asked about potentially securing his/her PHP code, my answer that OP doesn't use the needed filtering to prevent injections is no where near *“a tad over the top”*. Instead, it's pretty on-point.