# Regex validation for Email Address

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, email

I need to validate whether my regex is correct for below scenario. Suggestion's if the regex is correct:

[Wiki Link **Local_part**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Local_part)

The local-part of the email address may use any of these ASCII characters.[4] RFC 6531 permits Unicode characters beyond the ASCII range:

1. Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a–z, A–Z) (ASCII: 65–90,
   97–122)
2. Digits 0 to 9 (ASCII: 48–57)
3. These special characters: `! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _` { | } ~
   (limited support)
4. Character . (dot, period, full stop) (ASCII: 46) provided that it is
   not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not
   appear two or more times consecutively (e.g. John..Doe@example.com
   is not allowed).
5. Special characters are allowed with restrictions. They are:
6. Comments are allowed with parentheses at either end of the local
   part; e.g. "john.smith(comment)@example.com" and
   "(comment)john.smith@example.com" are both equivalent to
   "john.smith@example.com".
7. International characters above U+007F are permitted by RFC 6531,
   though mail systems may restrict which characters to use when
   assigning local parts.

The Regex:

```
^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~\/]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,5}$
```

[Demo Here](http://regex101.com/r/kN4nJ0)

Comment: What language are we talking about? Most languages have libraries for validating emails, and also, regex implementation differs between languages.

Comment: Oops sorry to mention. `.net`

Comment: `.net` is not a language, it's a framework.

Comment: ASP.NET with C# to be precise. :)

Comment: Can you provide some C# code where you perform this check?

Comment: I'd consider [tag:regex] to be a domain-specific language. Specifying [".NET Framework Regular Expressions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes it sufficiently concrete to be on-topic.

Comment: Being a killjoy: your regex is wrong (they all are). The only reliable way to validate an email address, is to send an email, and see if it gets to the destination. You have now hit the famous ['now you have two problems' problem](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: Is the set of all email addresses a [**`Regular`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) or [**`Context-Free`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) [*language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chomsky-hierarchy.svg)? If it is not, using a *PERL Compatible Regex* will not help you, you would need a *[full-blown parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/81427/1465011)*, a *[challenge-response protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_spam_filtering)*, or to *[relax your validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model)* technique.

Comment: As long as you can use non-greedy specifiers (for the comments), then regex should be all you need. You could use an optional grouping with a non-greedy "0 or more" specifier to support multiple comments.

Comment: In the case of .NET, the language used is irrelevant, what matters is the Regex library used, and without further info, it is the one supplied with the framework.

Answer (score 35):

I remember having read somewhere (possibly in another Code Review answer) that for an e-mail address, the simplest and most effective validation you can do is to make sure it contains an `@`. Making it more restrictive than that can often be a risk of invalidating some valid e-mails. You'd be surprised at some examples of valid e-mail addresses.

As an additional example, see the ["almost RFC 822 compatible regex" in this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28205/phpmailer-script-for-a-contact-form/32557#32557).

Keep it simple, and don't mark some e-mail addresses that are actually valid as invalid.

```
email.contains("@")
```

If you want to be more restrictive than this, use an existing and trusted library for the validation, don't try to make another regex.

For further reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Validation_and_verification
- [list of email addresses that can be used to test a javascript validation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297420/list-of-email-addresses-that-can-be-used-to-test-a-javascript-validation-script) on Stack Overflow
- http://codefool.tumblr.com/post/15288874550/list-of-valid-and-invalid-email-addresses

Comment: Thanks @simon for the [list of email addresses.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297420/list-of-email-addresses-that-can-be-used-to-test-a-javascript-validation-script)

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."——Jamie Zawinski on regular expressions; paraphrasing the Unix Haters Handbook on `sed`, paraphrasing David Tilbrook on `awk`. http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247 :)

Comment: The main point being that even if the address is syntactically correct, you have no idea whether it exists. If you need verification, send a verification link to the address.

Comment: @IngoBürk: That's true, but validation and verification are different things. There's no point verifying invalid data.

Comment: `If you want to be more restrictive than this, use an existing and trusted library for the validation` - In my experience, even library validators are broken. Since then, `email.contains("@")` is the only thing I'd ever do.

Comment: The problem is that everyone is wanting to be technically correct. Realistically, someone who creates an email address such as "!#$%&'+-/=.?^`{|}~@[1.0.0.127]" deserves to get invalidated and I have no problem rejecting those kinds of people on my sites.  I'd rather be strict and have clean data than relaxed and fill my DB with trash addresses.

Comment: email.contains("@") would return true for "bob@bob@bob@" I am all for simplicity and although I use regex sometimes realize it is not a solution to be used extensively, but any validation should actually *validate*.

Comment: @Slagmoth Sure, you could check that it only contains one `@`, but then there'll be other ways to pass through the validation. I believe that if someone enters an invalid e-mail address, it's a thousand times more likely that they spelled their name wrong than that they included an extra `@`.

Answer (score 20):

As @Simon pointed out, your regular expression might consider some valid addresses as invalid.

Per [this source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) which I've found somewhere on [this Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2049502/1188513), this would be RFC5322-compliant:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
  |  "(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]
      |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")
@ (?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
  |  \[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:
          (?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]
          |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)
     \])
```

Validating emails with a regular expression is ...more complicated than one would think, eh?

I agree with @Simon here, it's probably best to keep it simple, and go with a simple `string.Contains()` instead of a regular expression. If it's not a matter of life and death, ...*don't try to be a regex ninja!*

[image: XKCD#208]

Comment: Pretty much anything with an [xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com) comic gets an up vote.

Answer (score 13):

It was suggested that I move this to an answer instead of a comment:

Since you're using .NET, why not just use [`System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.MailAddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  It already performs validation in its [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it will throw a `FormatException` if the address is invalid.

This is particularly useful if you intend on using the address to actually send email, since you'll likely be using `Systen.Net.Mail.MailAddress` for it anyways.

This does not get you the regex, but I think a better solution is to avoid regex in this case for the reasons stated in the comments and other answers.

Comment: Why, *why*, **why**, ***WHY*** haven't I thought if this!?!! Here, have an upvote! ;)

Comment: +1 I've used this technique multiple times. If it's good enough for the .NET Framework, it's good enough for me. The really long catch-all-edge-cases regex formats are daunting. And they're never quite perfect.

Comment: This feels like you're using try/catch for control flow since you're forced to catch an exception in the invalid case while trying to validate.

Answer (score 3):

I follow the HTML5 spec for validation of email [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#valid-e-mail-address). (Note that it's not RFC 5322 compatible)

The regex for it is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

which is simple enough for my needs.

Comment: The important question IMO is not whether or not the regex is simple, it's whether or not it is correct. I believe this regex will incorrectly mark several unusual but valid addresses as invalid.

Comment: True, some will fail, but it has the advantage that the same validation that happens on the browser is also used on the server side. Also I suspect that soon all the "valid" emails that don't pass the check above (ie HTML5 validation) will be changed to be compatible with it.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Do you have some examples of valid ones not accepted by this regex?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: `I.am.a.valid"email address!"@email.host`. The spec is uh, quite flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to take a dependency on `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` then you can use the [`EmailAddressAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do all the heavy lifting for you. I tend to use it as an extension method as follows:

```cs
private static readonly EmailAddressAttribute EmailValidator = new EmailAddressAttribute();

public static bool IsValidEmail(this string email)
{
    // You can also add validation against length if you want
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) && EmailValidator.IsValid(email); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Email validation regex:

```
^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,5}$
```

Or

```
^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+[.])+[a-z]{2,5}$
```

[Test it out in this Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/kN4nJ0/53)

Answer (score 0):

```
const re_host = '(([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]+|([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})';
const re_localpart = '[a-z0-9!#\$%&\'*\+-/=\?\^_`{|}\~\.]+';
```

Take these two constants, and concatenate them like this `re_localpart + '@' + re_host` and you have a regular expression to validate an email address. Note that this is a PHP regex.